# Can't install DataDog MSI in Dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server, datadog

From everything I have read, I should be able to do this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ADD https://ddagent-windows-stable.s3.amazonaws.com/datadog-agent-7-latest.amd64.msi C:\datadog-agent-7-latest.amd64.msi
RUN Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/qn /i C:\datadog-agent-7-latest.amd64.msi APIKEY=abc123 /L*V C:\install.log'
```

It looks like it built correctly:

```
> docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
 ---> 71d3f266f3af
Step 2/4 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Running in 1d931a586756
Removing intermediate container 1d931a586756
 ---> 277770d39d39
Step 3/4 : ADD https://ddagent-windows-stable.s3.amazonaws.com/datadog-agent-7-latest.amd64.msi C:/datadog-agent-7-latest.amd64.msi
Downloading [==================================================>]  146.9MB/146.9MB
 ---> 93223b61dad3
Step 4/4 : RUN Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/qn /i C:\datadog-agent-7-latest.amd64.msi APIKEY="abc123" /L*V C:\install.log'
 ---> Running in 619d7bb20f3b
Removing intermediate container 619d7bb20f3b
 ---> ddc461e4525a
Successfully built ddc461e4525a
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

But when I check in the container to see if it installed in `C:\Program Files\Datadog`, I am not seeing any of the files I am expecting from the installation.

I added the flag to give the install some extra logs (/L*V C:\install.log) but didn't see much in there. I have confirmed the msiexec command works on a Windows host, just not in the Docker build from what I can tell. Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: what do you se when you build your docker image?

Comment: it is possible that just user during installation (docker build) and when you exec into it is different

Comment: Everything looks like it built correctly. I will update the post with the build results.

Comment: In my experience, the Datadog agent is meant to be installed on the host, not in all running containers on a given host. Otherwise, you're going to have to pass your api key in plaintext into every container for the agent configuration, which would be very insecure

Comment: I was planning on passing the key in at build time as part of CI but it sounds like this approach is maybe a dead end anyway since the installation doesn't seem to work inside the container.